# Design Patterns: Callback as a method parameter

Tags: java, design-patterns, methods, callback, method-parameters

I was wondering if defining a callback for a operation in a method parameter is worse than defining it in the object and setting via setters, concerning about design patterns.

I'm not sure if exists a design pattern regarding callback creations.

For example, let's say that there is some class A, and I want to execute a methodM with some callback.

```
public class A {
    public interface Callback {
        void onEvent();
    }
    public static methodM(...) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

May I do this:

```
public static void methodM(Callback c) {
    c.onEvent();
}
// ...
A.method(this); // The class that calls the method is the callback!
```

Instead of:

```
public static void setCallback(Callback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}
public static void methodM() {
    this.callback.onEvent();
}
// ...
A.setCallback(this); // The class that calls the method is the callback!
A.method();
```

Note that the fact of the method be static is just to easy the scenario understanding.

So, can I use the first approach as a valid design?

The reason about using the first scenario is to avoid memory leaks as to easy the definition of simple callbacks for multiple execution, since I would have to control a list of callbacks using either lists, observers, etc.

Comment: The highly depends on the class and the method's intent. There is no *one* pattern.

Comment: I know, is too generic, but i was afraid that the first approach be too bad/ugly to be used. As my callback is such a simple operation, I really wouldn't like to control a list of callbacks or something like this without no needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a "Callback pattern", it's too generic.

Yet, many Design patterns use callback, like [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) or [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

It will depends of the global architecture of your program

That piece of code

```
public static void methodM(Callback c) {
    c.onEvent();
}
// ...
A.method(this); // The class that calls the method is the callback!
```

does not bother me, it's not something forbidden if presented like this

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its not a matter of patterns but a few principles recommend to store the callback in a classfield.

- Single-Responsibility-Principle: Dont tell `A` what he has to do.
- Law of Demeter: No one else shall know what is the work `A` has to do.
- Open Close principle: You may like to call the Callback in some other situations someday.

There are some other principles, but i think these are the most important.